# Visual Studio 2015 / Cordova "Unable to start Debugging"

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have been able to debug my cordova app in VS2015 CTP5/6 for some time but once in a while I receive this error and then only a visual studio re-install will solve the problem.  However, at this point, there seems to be no remedy.  The event log doesn't show any info. I've tried running VS with the /log parm but there is no information in the log of why the debug is failing.  I have read the various posts here and elsewhere.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Is this a Cordova app you have created with the Cordova CLI or one you have created with Visual Studio's Tools for Apache Cordova?  And what is your platform and debugging target?  Ripple, an emulator, a connected device?

Comment: having the same problem with RTM. targeting ripple or device it doesn't matter. worked fine with RC. Uninstalled Installed everything and still no luck. help pls

Comment: I'm also having the same issue (with the latest/final release of VS 2015) - after having VS 2015 RC installed and working fine.

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm this solution works.

Close all VS instances

cd “%appdata%..\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools”

rename CoreCon folder

Launch VS again.