# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 - The template specified cannot be found when creating project with Cordova tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I did a clean installation of Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 Enterprise (MSDN Release Date 1/13/2016) after I had install Visual Studio 2015 Community where I installed the Apache Cordova tools components.

When creating a new project...

1. I do not see the node with the JavaScript templates anymore - though it is in the Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates structure
2. I get "The template specified cannot be found" with the new TypeScript TACO templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and trial/error loops I solved the problem with these steps

1. [MSDN forum entry](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/beeab15c-6766-46c5-ac99-46272beadccc/visual-studio-2015-installed-update1-lost-javascript-project-template?forum=vssetup)

> I uninstalled the visual studio 2015, delete the regedit key with visual studio 14, delete all the c:\xx\AppData\Local\Temp files and the install path, then reinstalled visual studio 2015 with update1

2. the TACO dependency checker (Tools>Options>Tools for Apache Cordova>Run Dependency Checker) indicated that the Android SDK is not installed. I followed the suggested links, installed it manually and rerun Android SDK manager and the checker until all required components where installed.

Now the JavaScript and TypeScript templates where available when creating a new project ... **but** the newly created projects did not contain any files - just the solution and the project.
I guess this is caused by the fact that I did not install VS2015 on the C: drive.

3. to fix this I executed as admin/elevated:

   ```
   cd /d "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE"
   devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates
   ```

Problem is fixed and I can create TACO projects with JavaScript and TypeScript.

Comment: after going thru all this I had the message "Unable to start debugging" which I fixed with [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785260/visual-studio-2015-cordova-unable-to-start-debugging)