# Visual Studio 2015 not showing templates saved

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, blend, visual-studio-2015

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bN43.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt7ZG.png)After Searching online for visual studio templates through the console within Visual Studio and downloading them, I can never find them again under saved templates. If I click on the same template in the console under "go online and search for templates" (now its already checked with a green circle, indicating that it has been downloaded already) and  try to start a new project it never fully compiles. Specifically Cordova templates. Within VS 2015 and VS Blend 2015. I can not find any sort of tutorial anywhere or documentation regarding this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you offer some specific steps or a screenshot of how you download the template?

Comment: What is one of the templates you tried? I'd like to try and replicate the issue - thanks!

Comment: So this dude is right about how to fix VS studio. Just try the devenv stuff at the bottom. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111107/visual-studio-2015-update-1-the-template-specified-cannot-be-found-when-creati) @KaiWalter However Blend is not fixed as well.

Comment: Meanwhile a friend is blowing up [Visual Studio Twitter](https://twitter.com/VisualStudio) and [we're on to something](https://twitter.com/VisualStudio/status/740654177571999744)

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair Visual Studio 15 and Tools for Apache Cordova two three times.

Comment: I need a scalpel not a nuke. Trust me, I went nuclear on that sob repairing, uninstalling, reinstalling. I tried some cray nonsense even at the cmd line. No avail. A friend and I have been working on this for about two weeks before we started reaching out for help. I thought I was going nuts. I think I am close to a solution.